# Declarative Authorization with a permissions join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, declarative-authorization

Users have permission to manage articles for particular combinations of location and category.

For example Dave may be allowed to manage HR articles for Paris. Paul may be allowed to manage Business articles for London.

The models and their associations are as follows:

- user has many permissions
- permission belongs to user, location and category
- category has many articles and permissions
- location has many articles and permissions
- article belongs to location and category

I can say:

```
has_permission_on :articles, :to => :manage do
  if_attribute :location => { :permissions => { :user_id => is {user.id} }, :category => { :permissions => { :user_id => is {user.id} } }
end
```

When I call permitted_to?(:delete) on an article record (whose category id is 1893 and location id is 2939), the following queries are run:

```
SELECT `categories`.*  FROM `categories`  WHERE `categories`.`id` = 1893 LIMIT 1
SELECT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` WHERE (`permissions`.category_id = 1893)
SELECT `locations`.*   FROM `locations`   WHERE `locations`.`id` = 2939 LIMIT 1
SELECT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` WHERE (`permissions`.location_id = 2939)
```

What I need to be run is really:

```
SELECT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` WHERE (`permissions`.category_id = 1893 AND `permissions`.location_id = 2939)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

**Update**

Ok, so I now have an instance method in the article model:

```
def permitted_user_ids
  Permission.select('user_id').where(:location_id => location_id, :category_id => category_id).map(&:user_id)
end
```

and my rule is now:

```
has_permission_on :articles, :to => :manage do
  if_attribute :permitted_user_ids => contains { user.id }
end
```

Now when I call permitted_to?(:delete) (or read/update/create/manage) on an article record whose category id is 1893 and location id is 2939, the following query is run:

```
SELECT user_id FROM `permissions` WHERE `permissions`.`category_id` = 1893 AND `permissions`.`location_id` = 2939
```

...which is exactly what I want.

Except, that the with_permissions_to scope is behaving very oddly.

```
Article.with_permissions_to(:read)
```

Now generates:

```
SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (`articles`.`id` = 9473)
```

...where 9473 is the ID of the current user!

I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subclasses and manage the permissions with [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).
You can have a top class Article and then all the kind of articles can be subclasses, and in the subclasses you use cancan to manage their permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I'm still at 45 :(

You say `permission` belongs to `user`, `location` and `category`.
Thus, the permissions table would have user_id, location_id and category_id columns.

If that is true, then why are you declaring that category `belongs_to` permission and location `belongs_to` permission? Surely the relation should be `has_many`?

You should use `has_many` in the model which DOES NOT have the foreign key(category and location), and `belongs_to` on the model WHICH DOES (permission).

Forgive me if all this is just a typo you made, and what you really meant was permission belongs_to user and has_many location and category.

Comment: You're right - permission belongs to user, location and category, and user, location and category each have many permissions - I've corrected the question. Cheers.